# How do I pass a class's functions and variables into setInterval?

Tags: typescript

I'm messing around with Angular and typescript, but I was having an issue setting up setInterval for something.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(function() { this.randomLink = this.cycleText(this.randomLink) }, 1)
}
```

As long as the page is open, this repeatedly results in:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.cycleText is not a function
    at home.component.ts:21
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27425)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:480)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2552)
```

So the interval is clearly working, but it doesn't look like it can use the function the way I'm trying to pass it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
setInterval(() => {
  this.randomLink = this.cycleText(this.randomLink);
}, 1);
```

// you need to use setInterval as an arrow function to know the elements outside it

Comment: That fixed it, thanks.  What allows this function to work over the one I was using?

Comment: @Rayalot72 this works because of the "arrow function" syntax, which preserves the value of `this`. [Read more on arrow functions here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)